# How to plot specific range of values on a histogram in python using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I've imported data from a .csv. There is a column within the data referring to number of people. The number of people ranges from 1 - 100 for each different input. My goal is to only plot on a histogram the inputs where number of people is less than 50.

I know how to plot the histogram.
df['people'].hist()

But, how do I specify the range of people?
I've tried df[df['people']< 50].hist() but that did not work.

I know this should be easy but I just don't get it! This is using python and pandas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used some sample data and tried to plot the histogram with `df['people'][df['people']<50].hist()` but `df[df['people']<50].hist()` also seems to work for me.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[1,1,2,3,3,5,7,8,9,10,
10,11,11,13,13,15,16,17,18,18,
18,19,20,21,21,23,24,24,25,25,
25,25,26,26,26,27,27,27,27,27,
29,30,30,31,33,34,34,34,35,36,
36,37,37,38,38,39,40,41,41,42,
43,44,45,45,46,47,48,48,49,50,
51,52,53,54,55,55,56,57,58,60,
61,63,64,65,66,68,70,71,72,74,
75,77,81,83,84,87,89,90,90,91], columns=['people'])

df.head()
df['people'][df['people']<50].hist()
```

I have attached a screenshot of the [histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q2ax.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

Try it with query function

```
df.query("people < 50")['people'].hist()
```